# Magento 1.7.0.2 stuck on import data check

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.7

We have recently installed magento 1.7.0.2 and set up a store where we have imported over 6000 product without any problems.

Now we have added 2 more websites in that instalation and after that we  have got the problem that we can't import anymore. when we upload the csv it hangs on cheking data

the execution time limit is already changed into 300

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem solved.

A core file was changed, now lets find out by who or what

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a good dedicated server? Because 6000 products in 3 stores could add as much as 18K rows into some product tables.

How much product are you plain to import into your store?

Answer (score 0):

You should just change the mysql cvs size up to the high number. The problem will be solved.

Comment: What is cvs size? Do you mean "csv size"?